# Replace elements in numpy array using list of old and new values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to replace elements in a numpy array using a list of old values and new values. See below for a code example (`replace_old` is the requested method). The method must work for both int, float and string elements. How do I do that?

```
import numpy as np

dat = np.hstack((np.arange(1,9), np.arange(1,4)))
print dat # [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3]

old_val = [2, 5]
new_val = [11, 57]

new_dat = replace_old(dat, old_val, new_val)
print new_dat # [1 11 3 4 57 6 7 8 1 11 3]
```

Comment: An optimal answer would depend rather strongly on the typical sizes of the arrays involved, I suppose. Do you have any indications?

Comment: Not really, likely around ~1M observations. However, performance is not that critical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.place`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html) :

```
>>> np.place(dat,np.in1d(dat,old_val),new_val)
>>> dat
array([ 1, 11,  3,  4, 57,  6,  7,  8,  1, 11,  3])
```

For creating the *mask* array you can use `np.in1d(arr1,arr2)` which will give you :

> a boolean array the same length as ar1 that is True where an element of ar1 is in ar2 and False otherwise

**Edit**:Note that the preceding recipe will replace `old_values` based on those order and as @ajcr mentioned it wont work for another arrays,so as a general way for now I suggest the following way using a loop (which I don't think that was the best way):

```
>>> dat2 = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2])
>>> old_val = [1, 2]
>>> new_val = [33, 66]

>>> z=np.array((old_val,new_val)).T
>>> for i,j in z:
...    np.place(dat2,dat2==i,j)
... 
>>> dat2
array([33, 66, 33, 66])
```

In this case you create a new array (`z`) which is contains the relevant pairs from `old_val` and `new_val` and then you can pass them to `np.place` and replace them .

Comment: Nice and numpythonic solution; I expect this to be near-optimal for all but tiny arrays. However, a solution involving np.put may be slightly more efficient still, as it avoids the allocation and iteration of a full mask array.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn yeah, But  since `np.put` need to fine the relevant indices for each element and doing this job may not be easy I think using `np.place` is more appropriate here!

Comment: Be careful: this won't work quite as you expect. Try `dat = [1, 2, 1, 2]`, `old_val = [1, 2]` and `new_val = [33, 66]`. This method returns `[33, 66, 33, 33]`. The last element of the array does not get replaced properly.

Comment: @ajcr Seems that you are right, let me fix that! thanks for attention!

Comment: @Kasra: I read the OP's question as wanting every `1` to be replaced by `33` and every `2` to be replaced with `66`. I like your suggested method very much, but it doesn't work in quite this way. (If I'm wrong and it is what the OP wants I'll happily delete the comment.)

Comment: @ajcr: Good catch, that is indeed not the intended behavior.

Comment: @ajcr thanks again! I edited the answer but I think It can be done more elegant! what you think?